# "You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>" - but I am in a router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My code sandbox is here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-platform-5p28y

I'm getting the error:

```
You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>
```

But I am in a router:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <Route
...

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

What exactly is going on here? Why does React not think I am inside a router?

Comment: There is something wrong with `AnimatedSwitch`.

Comment: Any idea what it could be?

Comment: https://github.com/maisano/react-router-transition/issues/102

Answer (score -1):

Well first lets get those components (Cards and Map) out of there. Also it seems that Animated Switch has some issues (looking at 23 issues on NPM). So i removed it for you. This will run. Also i deleted some of the other code in Index.js for my own convenience (your history and such). You will need to ad those back in

Create Cards.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from "react";

class Cards extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="cards">
        {this.state.list.map((carditem, index) => (
          <div className="card">{carditem}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Cards;
```

then Create map.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from "react";

class Map extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Map would appear here</div>;
  }
}

export default Map;
```

In Index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import { AnimatedSwitch } from "react-router-transition";
import configureStore, { history } from "./store";
import { Provider, ReactReduxContext } from "react-redux";
import Cards from './Cards';
import Map from './Map';





const routing = (
  <Router>

    <Route exact path="/" component={Cards} />
    <Route path="/about/" component={Map}/>
</Router>
    )

    ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```